# How I can downgrade from U3 to U1 "oreo to nougat"

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, 7.0-nougat, 8.1-oreo, downgrade

I want to downgrade my phone from Oreo to Nougat
My phone is Samsung J730F.

But the problem is that Samsung locked the boot-louder.

Can I go back by flashing the phone combination ROM then flash my phone with stock ROM to bypass this lock?

**Note:** FRP, google account protection is OFF and USB debugging is ON.

And I have rooted the phone and flash it with combination ROM.

**My question is what should I do after flashing it combination ROM?
Should I flash stock ROM 4 files or replace only some files?**

Answer (score 2):

> How I can downgrade from U3 to U1?

The short answer is you cannot. the `u#` is the bootloader version. The bootloader is protected by rollback protection fuses:

Rollback Prevention (RP)

> Rollback Prevention blocks the device from loading or flashing an approved but old version of 
>   boot components. Old versions of software may contain known vulnerabilities that 
>   attackers can exploit. Rollback prevention checks the version of the bootloader and kernel 
>   during both boot and updates, and blocks these processes from continuing if versions are 
>   unacceptably old. The lowest acceptable version of the bootloader is stored in secure hardware 
>   fuses when the device is flashed, and the lowest acceptable version of the kernel is stored in the 
>   bootloader itself. Whenever a vendor-applied update occurs, the lowest acceptable version can 
>   be incremented in the fuses. Because this value is kept in fuses, it cannot be decremented even 
>   through physical tampering.
>   Rollback Prevention fuses are set at manufacturing time in the Samsung factory to prevent old 
>   firmware versions from overwriting newer ones.

This is from Samsung technical notes but it is a [.pdf Download](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://kp-cdn.samsungknox.com/b9821c47b3ef1cce894325a61a6fcdac.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiJg7WCvcrfAhUEZN8KHWjdBZsQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3t8DHqfb9iJM6NQx2pxNAQ&cshid=1546273872797).

Flashing back to stock will not help either since it an issue with Samsung Knox securities. It will most likely end with a fatal error like:

`SW REV. CHECK FAIL(BOOTLOADER) DEVICE: 3, BINARY: 1`

Mixing and matching stock firmware files maybe be possible but is an increase risk to bricking your device. If you try I would make sure to have multiple devices or multiple reports of success. Also **double check to make sure if a workaround is found that it has not been patched or you have the firmware version it works for**.

There might be an exploit to bypass this though I have not seen one for your specific device to downgrade oreo to nougat.

Another possibility could be a [custom ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7-2017/development) downgrade to the android version you want that does not downgrade the bootloader.