# Galaxy S8 Stuck After Update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

My Galaxy S8 is now locked on the Samsung screen after receiving an Android update via Verizon. According to the Samsung site, it was running Android™ 7.0 (Nougat). I have attempted a hard and soft reset then moved on to Odin.

I downloaded Odin v3.13 and using the latest firmware version of Nougat from the Updato site my attempts to restore my phone continue to fail. Recommendations? Thanks for reading.  [image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply what info would I be looking for? I see - Carrier - VZW; RPMB fuse blown; RPMB Provisioned; Current Binary: Samsung Official; FRP Lock: On; Warranty Void: 0x0; Qualcomm Secureboot: Enable; RP SWREV: B7(2.1.1.1.1) K6 S7; Secure Download: Enable; DID: 205ED0955789.    Where would I find the Odin log files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can downgrade from U3 to U1 "oreo to nougat"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205892/how-i-can-downgrade-from-u3-to-u1-oreo-to-nougat)

Comment: not sure about the FRP lock as well...doing some reading. I guess the challenge is finding the correct FW version. This is all new to me..thx

Comment: From reading it appears that FRP is only engaged after the phone is working. Is there a way to find the correct FW version?

Comment: sure you have S8 (not S8+)? just search for G95\*FXXU7\*\*\*\*

Comment: Hmmm...S8 on the phone and Samsung says S8, SM-G950U, so I'm fairly confident.

Comment: the last letter is also important because that devices shipped in two different chipset (Exynos/Qualcomm) look at sticker for the exact model no

Comment: Excellent...thanks. I have started a new download based on Frija's results.

Comment: Still failing with the latest FW...any recommendations?

Comment: FYI...you must run Odin as an Administrator.

Comment: if that was the solution please post that as answer, not comment