# Missing OEM unlock toggle on Samsung Galaxy S9

Tags: samsung, bootloader-lock, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I've found numerous guides online on how to fix the missing OEM unlock toggle on Samsung Galaxy S9 (SM-G960U) running Android 10. I've been able to follow all steps except for the last one before rebooting the phone. And that step is going into software update and unchecking ***download updates automatically*** and checking ***download updates manually***. The problem is that those options don't exist!

I can only tap on ***Check for updates*** and there's a grayed-out option that says ***Continue update***. I don't know if this is true, but I think it's the same as going into developer options and switching off ***auto-update system***, which I was able to do.

Either way, I still wasn't able to fix the missing button, even after following [this guide](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/fix-missing-oem-unlock-toggle-samsung-galaxy-devices/#supported-devices) I was just talking about. I've seen other guides and they talk about the same thing that this one does.

Can someone help me unlock my OEM unlock button, please?

---

As of now, I played around with my phone and found out the reboot to bootloader option in the menu after starting the phone with **power key + volume up + Bixby key**. I didn't know what that was going to do but when I selected that, a light blue screen came on and said `downloading... do not turn off target`. There's an option to cancel it, but I want to see what happens.

Maybe I didn't have a bootloader at all? (sounds crazy because I need a bootloader to start my phone, so maybe it's downloading something else?). In either case, I'll keep this question posted with any new info.

Comment: guess U models are not unlockable. what is your chipset, csc, bootloader version

Comment: How do I check any of those things? I can't find it in about phone

Comment: I've backed up my data via SD Card and cloud. Is that going to help at all? BTW I think the csc code is ATT

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232732

Comment: So my bootloader version is 190711 because it's the 5th digit from the build number (or 1 if that's the only digit you're looking for)

Comment: carrier-branded phones sold by Verizon or AT&T will not have an unlockable bootloader

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119756/discussion-between-matthew-schell-and-alecxs).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 7-day wait mentioned in [millertime90's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/243063), that is completely untrue. I've had mine for over 2 months, and never showed the OEM unlock. I did hear though that one certain version allows it but the G960**U** cannot.

Also, that blue screen is called "Download Mode". It's used for when using Odin or other tools to reflash/flash images to your device.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We appreciate everyone's contribution, though please understand that [unlike most forums, we prefer to have less chatty conversations](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour). Also, please note that we might have to moderate every post to keep them under the policy, either by [editing](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/editing) or [deleting](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) them. I hope we can work together contributing here while also following the norms. Thanks for your understanding :)

Answer (score -3):

You have to wait 7 days after enabling developer mode, and OEM with show up

Comment: Hello. Where did you read this, or on which Android device did you test this?

Comment: AFAIK, this applies to [Xiaomi devices](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/do-i-have-no-option-but-to-wait-for-168-hours-7-days-to-unlock-my-phones-bootloader.4322429/), but I don't think Samsung has this policy.