# Disconnected phone while installing a ROM on Samsung Galaxy S10

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I tried to install a ROM in my Samsung Galaxy S10 5G, but after a minute, my phone suddenly disconnected from my PC and the following message appeared:

> (이 휴대전화의 부트스트랩 로더 잠금이 해제되어 있고 소프트웨어 무결정이 인증되지 않았습니다. 이 휴대전화의 데이터가 손상될 수 있습니다. 중요하거나 민감한 정보는 여기에 저장하지 않는 것을 권장합니다. 계속하려면 전원 버튼을 누르세요)

Google Translate:

> (This phone's bootstrap loader is unlocked and software integrity has not been authenticated. Data on this phone may be compromised. We recommend that you do not store any important or sensitive information here. Press the power button to continue press)

Since then, I can't get into recovery mode again. I tried several ways to open the recovery mode to start over the installation but doesn't work. Now I don't know what to do?

Comment: you need to enter download mode and flash with Odin3. try to avoid upgrades if you have any plans on customizing https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232732